# How can pass the value of a binding variable to another binding variable in two DatePicker in SwiftUI?

Tags: datepicker, swiftui

I have two `DatePicker` in a `Form`. The start date of the second one depends on the date of the first `DatePicker`. It can be solved with `PartialRangeFrom`, but the binding object used as selection, doesn't change.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var startDate: Date = Date()
    @State private var endDate: Date = Date()

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            DatePicker(selection: $startDate, displayedComponents: .date, label: { Text("Start date") })

            DatePicker(selection: $endDate, in: startDate..., displayedComponents: .date, label: { Text("End date") })

        }
    }
}
```

The second date picker does change and refreshes when first datepicker changes, but the label, linked with `$endDate`, doesn't change, it still continues showing the initialization value.

How can I do something like `self.endDate = self.startDate` in  label and wheel refresh at the same time the first datepicker changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a new **struct** that has the properties: startdate and enddate and inside that struct use observer func **didSet**. Here is the example of the code.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var model = DateRangeModel()

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            DatePicker(selection: $model.startDate, displayedComponents: .date, label: { Text("Start date") })

            DatePicker(selection: $model.endDate, in: model.startDate..., displayedComponents: .date, label: { Text("End date") })

        }

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


struct DateRangeModel {
    var endDate: Date = Date()
    var startDate: Date = Date() {
        didSet {
             endDate = startDate
        }
       }
}
```